# Make a new type definition compatible with all modules

Tags: types, module, julia

I am working on a somewhat large project (around 2000 lines) and for better code organization I wanted to divide my functions in modules, each one of them in a separate file.

Most of my functions take as an argument a variable of a custom type `Typ`, whose definition is large and I also wanted to put it in a separate file `type.jl`.

The problem is that when I try to create a module `module1`, if I just do `include("type.jl")`, the module then creates its own version of the code in `type.jl` and creates a type `module1.Typ`, and that type can't be used as an argument for functions of another module `module2`.

My idea for solving this is making the type `Typ` definition on `Base` so that all modules can access to the same type and define functions over it. What I want, in the end, is to be able to have the following structure.

In a file `type.jl`

```
struct Typ
   xs::Array{Int64,1}
   ys::Array{Int64,1}
   Typ(xs,ys) = new(xs,ys)
end
```

In a file `module1.jl`:

```
module module1
   function func1(x::Typ)
      return length(x.xs)
   end
end
```

In a file `module2.jl`:

```
module module2
   function func2(x::Typ)
      return length(x.ys)
   end
end
```

And being able to run all of these in a file called `main.jl`

```
include("type.jl")
include("module1.jl")
include("module2.jl")
b = Typ([0,0],[1,1])
module1.function1(b)
module2.function2(b)
```

I have tried to use `Base.include(Base,"type.jl")` before the module declaration but It doesn't work.

The only solution I have figured out is to not make modules and just define the functions inside the files. This works, but for debugging and making changes in the future I would rather have the module structure as it allows me to have an identifier for each function of which file contains its definition.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to do the following:

```
module module1
   import ..Typ
   function func1(x::Typ)
      return length(x.xs)
   end
end
```

(and all will work assuming you load type.jl file earlier)

The `..` tells Julia to look for a definition of `Typ` in a module enclosing the given module.